# Unable to compile thrift-0.9.0 on Centos6.4

Tags: qt, qt4, thrift

I have followed all the instructions mentioned in the Apache thrift wiki. I downloaded the thrift source code, then installed the dependencies

```
sudo yum install automake libtool flex bison pkgconfig gcc-c++ boost-devel libevent-devel zlib-devel python-devel ruby-devel
```

Then ran

```
./configure
```

(didn't run bootstrap.sh because there is no bootstrap.sh in the thrift-0.9.0 codebase). Finally, I get this error. Any idea why this is happening?

```
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libthriftz.la" && ln -s "../libthriftz.la" "libthriftz.la" )
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I/usr/include -I./src -I./src/thrift -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtNetwork    -Wall -g -O2 -MT libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.Tpo -c -o libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.lo `test -f 'src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp' || echo './'`src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I/usr/include -I./src -I./src/thrift -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -Wall -g -O2 -MT libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.Tpo -c src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.o
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:14:2: error: #error "This file was generated using the moc from 4.8.1. It"
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:15:2: error: #error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:16:2: error: #error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:47: error: no 'void apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' member function declared in class 'apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer'
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:62: error: 'const QMetaObjectExtraData apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer::staticMetaObjectExtraData' is not a static member of 'class apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer'
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:63: error: 'qt_static_metacall' was not declared in this scope
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:64: error: too many initializers for 'const QMetaObjectExtraData'
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:68: error: 'staticMetaObjectExtraData' was not declared in this scope
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:69: error: too many initializers for 'QMetaObject::<anonymous struct>'
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp: In member function 'virtual int apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
src/thrift/qt/moc_TQTcpServer.cpp:95: error: 'qt_static_metacall' was not declared in this scope
make[4]: *** [libthriftqt_la-moc_TQTcpServer.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rjain/Downloads/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rjain/Downloads/thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rjain/Downloads/thrift-0.9.0/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rjain/Downloads/thrift-0.9.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I download the source from: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Your qt-devel is out of date for thrift. Just remove the qt-devel rpm and rerun the configure script which will skip this part. It works for me.
First of all, check your qt related rpms by executing the following command

```
rpm -qa | grep qt-devel
```

If you find qt-devel is installed version below 4.6, please remove this package by executing command

```
rpm -qa | grep qt-devel | xargs rpm -e
```

If this is done, the qt part of thrift will be skipped.

Comment: you should add a sample of what you mean, original posts can be edited and change over time. It will also help other readers understand what you mean better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of Qt that is on your system is older than what this program expects. Can you try updating Qt to a later version?

```
sudo yum install qt4-devel
```

Comment: It says it exists and the latest version. [rjain@localhost thrift-0.9.0]$ sudo yum install qt4 qt4-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * epel: mirrors.solfo.com
 * extras: mirrors.usc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.kernel.org
Setting up Install Process
Package 1:qt-4.6.2-26.el6_4.i686 already installed and latest version
Package 1:qt-devel-4.6.2-26.el6_4.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Added the Qt tags, maybe someone that has a better understanding of Qt will be able to chime in.

Comment: Homer is right. you cannot compile it against QT 4.6. thrift requires QT 4.8.1 as far as i read from the error. Try manually compiling a newer QT-Version or look for a repository having a backport for your Linux Version. Eventually you can just download the QT for Linux from qt-project and install it locally for your user. But this messes up the system quite a bit... I wonder if you can run a qmake (having installed qt sdk for your version) within in your thrift source tree. This would use the 4.6 moc, but if thrift uses 4.8 methods you are left to start over.